# Error al desplegar snapshot a maven central

Tags: maven

Tengo problema al tratar de autenticarme en Maven central al tratar de desplegar mi plugin programáticamente.

En mi archivo de configuración, `settings.xml` puse el tóken que me genera al iniciar sesión en [el nuevo repositorio que me indicaron](https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/) para maven central.

Si a alguien le interesa mi número de ticket es el https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-67968

Mi módulo es una aplicación open source multiplataforma desarrollada en [java](/questions/tagged/java) con [dukescript](/questions/tagged/dukescript) y es un proyecto maven multomódulo

trato de correr el comando mvn deploy lo que me produce la siguiente traza:

```
Installing C:\Users\Administrador.000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\regextester\client-idea\target\regextester-idea-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar.asc to C:\Users\Administrador.000\Documents\NetBeansProjects\regextester\target\nexus-staging\deferred\org\javapro\regextester-idea\1.0.3-SNAPSHOT\regextester-idea-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar.asc
Deploying remotely...
Bulk deploying locally gathered artifacts from directory: 
 * Bulk deploying locally gathered snapshot artifacts
Downloading from ossrh: https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/javapro/regextester-nb/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading to ossrh: https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/javapro/regextester-nb/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/regextester-nb-1.0.3-20210425.202334-1.nbm
Progress (1): 4.1/254 kB
Progress (1): 254 kB    
                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary for regextester 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:

regextester ........................................ SUCCESS [ 26.666 s]
regextester JavaScript Libraries ................... SUCCESS [ 18.033 s]
automatonosgi ...................................... SUCCESS [  3.992 s]
generex OSGi Bundle ................................ SUCCESS [  4.865 s]
regextester General Client Code .................... SUCCESS [ 17.712 s]
regextester Client for Web ......................... SUCCESS [ 23.492 s]
regextester Client for NetBeans .................... SUCCESS [ 26.537 s]
regextester Client for Idea ........................ FAILURE [ 17.669 s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  02:21 min
Finished at: 2021-04-25T15:23:35-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project regextester-idea: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact org.javapro:regextester-nb:nbm:1.0.3-20210425.202334-1 from/to ossrh (https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): Transfer failed for https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/javapro/regextester-nb/1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/regextester-nb-1.0.3-20210425.202334-1.nbm 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Partes relevantes de mi settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<server>
  <id>ossrh</id>
  <username>v1234</username>
  <password>12346</password>
</server>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <gpg.passphrase>lacontraseñaquelepusealgpg</gpg.passphrase>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>jboss-public-repository</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>Maven Central</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>Google</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>ossrh</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Mi pom.xml del padre:

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.javapro</groupId>
<artifactId>regextester-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>regextester</name>
<url>https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester</url>
<modules>
    <module>js</module>
    <module>automatonosgi</module>
    <module>generex</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>client-web</module>
    <module>client-netbeans</module>
    <module>client-idea</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <net.java.html.version>1.7.1</net.java.html.version>
    <openjfx.version>16</openjfx.version>
    <bck2brwsr.version>0.32</bck2brwsr.version>
    <bck2brwsr.obfuscationlevel>MINIMAL</bck2brwsr.obfuscationlevel>
    <junit.browser.version>1.0</junit.browser.version>
    <jersey.version>2.13</jersey.version>
    <presenters.version>1.7.1</presenters.version>
    <enforcer.fail>false</enforcer.fail>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <idea.version>2020.1.4</idea.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dukescript.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-osgi</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dukescript.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-browser-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.browser.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.netbeans.html</groupId>
                    <artifactId>net.java.html</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.netbeans.html</groupId>
                    <artifactId>net.java.html.boot</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apidesign.bck2brwsr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>emul</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-versions</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <DependencyConvergence/>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>${enforcer.fail}</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/**/RegexTesting*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eluder.coveralls</groupId>
            <artifactId>coveralls-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <repoToken>${env.repoToken}</repoToken>
                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>downloadIC</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals><goal>download-single</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>https://www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases/com/jetbrains/intellij/idea/ideaIC/${idea.version}/</url>
                        <fromFile>ideaIC-${idea.version}.zip</fromFile>
                        <toFile>${project.basedir}/client-idea/lib/ideaIC-${idea.version}.zip</toFile>
                        <skipIfExists>true</skipIfExists>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="unzipping file ${project.basedir}/client-idea/lib/ideaIC-${idea.version}.zip to ${project.basedir}/client-idea/lib" />
                            <unzip src="${project.basedir}/client-idea/lib/ideaIC-${idea.version}.zip" dest="${project.basedir}/client-idea/lib" overwrite="false" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- generate source code jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- generate documentation jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    
        <!-- plugins for releasing to maven central -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins> 
</build>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Ruslan Lopez Carro</name>
        <id>javatlacati</id>
        <email>mi correo</email>
        <timezone>-6</timezone>
        <roles>
            <role>Project Founder</role>
            <role>Developer</role>
            <role>Mantainer</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
</developers>

<issueManagement>
    <url>https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester/issues</url>
    <system>GitHub Issues</system>
</issueManagement>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>GNU General Public License v3.0</name>
        <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>manual</distribution>
        <comments>
        </comments>
    </license>

</licenses>

 <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/javatlacati/regextester</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/javatlacati/regextester.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:javatlacati/regextester.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>regextester-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</tag>
</scm>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>releases</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.8</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

cabe mencionar que lo corro conforma a las instrucciones para desplegar como snapshot que [proporcionan oficialmente](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-maven/)

es decir:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás tratando de subir un SNAPSHOT a Maven Central. Solo puedes subir versiones de RELEASE (ergo, sin el sufijo SNAPSHOT).

Comment: ya agregué en la pregunta el enlace a las instrucciondes de como desplegar como snapshot en maven central, lo cual ha sido posible desde siempre